# How to add a simple quote into a text string?

Tags: excel

I have a name list like

```
Horak
Marek
Tihoun
etc...
```

and I want

```
'Horak'
'Marek'
'Tihoun'
```

I'm quite new to Excel, is there a way how to do that?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your data is in column `A`, isn't this as straight-forward as something like:

```
="'" & A1 & "'"
```

This will concatenate the quote `'` with the data in A1 with another quote `'`.

Answer (score 0):

If Horak was in cell A1 put the following in cell B1 and drag down for as many rows as you have entries in column A.

```
="'"&A1&"'"
```

You could also use

```
=CONCATENATE("'",B2,"'")
```

Example usage shown:

[image: Usage]

Answer (score 0):

That can be done through the following ways...

When you want to add the `'` to text by `&`

```
="'"&"Horak"&"'"
```

When you want to add the `'` to column  by `&`

```
="'" & [ColumnIndex] & "'"
```

When you want to add the `'` to column  by `CONCATENATE()`

```
=CONCATENATE("'",[ColumnIndex],"'")
```